# Kilz over old oil based finished exterior ceiling yes or no

Tags: painting, exterior

Can you put water based kilz over an old exterior ceiling that was finished with oil paint 20 yrs ago ? I want to put a latex finish on it and I want to seal it with kilz 2, is it ok to do this ?

Comment: Kilz is a brand. [What product are you asking about](http://www.kilz.com/products/primer)?

Comment: @isherwood If it's mentioned without anything else, Kilz generally refers to a primer

Comment: *I* know this, and *you* know this, but the community in general does not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but you will want to ensure the existing old oil-based paint is properly deglossed and clean to ensure a good bond with the water-based Kilz.

Answer (score 0):

I have used an airless paint sprayer to apply water-based Kilz to cover/seal interior and exterior oil-based paints, and never had any issues.

Answer (score 0):

If there's question, I would use the oil based(mineral spirit cleanup) Kilz instead. I had a ceiling that was old and would bleed every time I painted. Added some oil-based primer and painted again. No problems. Oil-base primer is the gold standard for any kind of repainting.